# Identify lost Socket connection without opening its IO stream

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

My `SocketServer` first listens for **at least 4** `Socket` connections before creating a WorkerThread where all four connections are served. And in the same thread, all 4 sockets will be opened to perform communication with connected clients.

Now, consider a situation where server has already accepted two socket connections, but listening to remaining 2 clients, before it can proceed with creating thread.

And while that listening phase, the connected clients are shown "Waiting..." message (since server has not yet opened the sockets to send any response back to clients, and `socket.readObject()` is blocking at client-end), till the server gets all 4 clients to work with. And in the meantime, one of the "already-connected" client kills that "Waiting..." thing, and closes the client app. In such a case, my WorkerThread will fire an exception due to dead socket supplied, when it attempts to open it.

How can I know if a socket is pointing to nothing (since client is lost) without having to open the socket? (since if I open it from main thread, I'll not be able to open it again from WorkerThread, where it is actually supposed to be used).

If I get to know if Socket is dead, I can get server back to listening and attempt to get 4 connections, before it proceeds creating a thread.

I know my `SocketServer` will be stuck at `accept()` so even if its possible to check what I asked above, I'll have to create another thread that monitors liveliness of already "accepted" socket connections.

### Update

I mean by not opening the socket is something like below.

```
Socket s = ss.accept();
/* I'll not be doing as below, since once I close InputStream and OutputStream in main Thread, I can't open in WorkerThread.
But I still want to know if Socket s is connected to client, before I start WorkerThread.


ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
String msg = in.readObject().toString();
System.out.println("Client Says:");
out.writeObject("success");
in.close();
out.close();

*/
new WorkerThread(s).start();
```

And note that my server is accepting 4 such connections, and when 4 sockets are `accept()`ed, it passes all 4 in `WorkerThread`'s constructor, and gets back to `accept()` another 4 clients.

Comment: I think you just need to handle your acceptions better.  Maybe send a "still waiting" message to the client to get an ACK every so often while you are waiting for the other connections.

Comment: @Gray: How can I send "Still Waiting" without opening the Socket (which is the restriction here)? or is it possible to exchange IO streams of socket between threads (sort of passing it through `WorkerThread` class' constructor).

Comment: I think you are going to have to "open" the socket.  Really you have already opened it once the `accept()` returns -- you just haven't written anything down it yet.

Comment: @Gray: Yeah, but opening IO streams to read and write into the socket is where I'm troubled, I can't reopen IO streams. :-(

Comment: My point is that the IO streams are _already_ opened @Kush.  You won't be "reopen"ing them, you'd just be getting the associated streams from the socket again.

Comment: @Gray: I can't get what do you mean by "associating" already open streams. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962736/opening-read-write-streams-multiple-times-from-a-socket/

Comment: You can't _close_ and reopen the stream but you can use the stream in two different places in your code -- just not at the same time.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The server doesn't 'open sockets' at all, it *accepts* them. The client opens sockets.

Comment: @Gray: Ok, so what I get hint from your comment is that if I just use `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` of the connected socket in main thread, but don't use `close()`, then I'll be able to access the stream at both places.

Comment: Yes.  Not at the same time but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to handle your acceptions better.  You should handle the `IOException` correctly whenever you try to read or write to the socket.

One option is to have the accepting code send a "still waiting" message to the client and get an acknowledge every so often while you are waiting for the other connections.  The socket and associated streams have already been created by the `accept()` so you can do this, call `flush()` on the `OutputStream`, and then hand off to the handler.

As long as you don't call `close()` on the streams, you should be able to re-use them without a problem.  You just can't have two different threads using the streams at the same time.